# Any tips on writing testing-friendly code?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Are there any guidelines for writing test-friendly Python code?

What I believe:

- One method does one thing.
- Don't use side-effects.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: import this, read understand implement

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### TDD

The best tip I can give you to write test friendly code is to write the tests first. Then write the production code (TDD). [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin) devised three simple rules to write [TDD](http://www.javiersaldana.com/articles/tech/refactoring-the-three-laws-of-tdd):

> 1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a
>    failing unit test pass.
> 2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient
>    to fail; and compilation failures are
>    failures.
> 3. You are not allowed to write any more production code than is
>    sufficient to pass the one failing
>    unit test.

Especially this quote should sink in:

> If you think about this you will
> realize that you simply cannot write
> very much code at all without
> compiling and executing something.
> Indeed, this is really the point.

### Writing Testable Code

Also read "[Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/)" from google's testing expert(are for java, but also apply to python for large parts). You should also download/read the [complete PDF](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf) on that page. But a quick recap:

> 1. Constructor does Real Work
> 2. Digging into Collaborators
> 3. Brittle Global State & Singletons
> 4. Class Does Too Much

Answer (score 7):

Write methods that don't rely on other models or resources - if they need to access them, they should be passed in to the method.

Comment: Is this mean for using dependency injection in our method?

Answer (score 6):

Alfred‘s answer is great, but I would add one thing for the questioner:

If you want to read a book, that is all about testing in Python using pytest, I suggest you to read „Python Testing with pytest: Simple, Rapid, Effective, and Scalable“ by Brian Okken. It’s perfect for what you want to do and it’s brand new (published September 2017).

Comment: Please use comments for such posts.

Comment: I‘m not allowed to comment on answers  different from mine, because of the low reputation as a new user. That’s why I added a normal answer.